# Region issue for IBM Cloud Activity Tracker with LogDNA

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

We have different resource group
A resource in Tokyo
B resource in Tokyo too

we need create one IBM Cloud Activity Tracker with LogDNA  for A resource
and another one IBM Cloud Activity Tracker with LogDNA  for B resource

Can i put IBM Cloud Activity Tracker for A resource in Tokyo
and IBM Cloud Activity Tracker for A resource in Dallas？

Because in your guide https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA-launch
there is important notice "There is 1 instance per region."

Could you help to confirm this case?

Answer (score 1):

Events are logged in the region where they are generated. Also note that [all global events are sent to LogDNA in Frankfurt (Europe)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA-event_types#event_types_global).

When working with the logged events, you can distinguish between the services based on the records and their data fields. You could [create custom views to separate those events](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA-views).

Comment: thanks for your reply,
back to my case, since my dev cluster resource and production cluster resource are in same region tokyo.I already set up dev activity tracker in tokyo,
if i want to set up another one to track activity for my production cluster resource. which region do i need to choose?
if answer is Tokyo, whether it will conflict with guide "There is 1 instance per region"
@data_henrik

Comment: You can only create one instance per region. In your case both the dev and production events would be sent to the same instance - if you use both dev and production in the same account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to effectively name your environments and work with [Event fields](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA-event) and [Event types](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA-event_types)

> A basic convention could use a pattern of “department_instance_level.”
> Instead of “Error Logs” and “Info Logs,” they would be named
> “dev_app1_info,” “qa_app2_error,” and so on. Not only does this
> clearly define the contents of each view, but since LogDNA sorts views
> alphabetically, each view is naturally grouped with similar views.
> This makes it easy to scan for specific views and search for those
> containing specific keywords. In this screenshot, searching for “prod”
> narrows the list to views containing production environment logs.

Check [How to use LogDNA Views to Manage Logs Effectively](https://logdna.com/guide-logdna-views/) guide to learn the best way to manage your events

Additionally, you are planning to setup multiple environments, check this guide around [How to Set Up Multiple Environments in LogDNA](https://logdna.com/how-to-deploy-logdna-to-different-teams-in-your-organization/)